# Create file inside new directory in vim in one step?

Tags: vim

While in vim I want to create a new file called `blog_spec.rb` inside `[working directory]/spec/models/`, but the directory doesn't exist yet?

What's the fastest way to create the directory and start editing the file? Any oneliners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
function s:MKDir(...)
    if         !a:0 
           \|| stridx('`+', a:1[0])!=-1
           \|| a:1=~#'\v\\@<![ *?[%#]'
           \|| isdirectory(a:1)
           \|| filereadable(a:1)
           \|| isdirectory(fnamemodify(a:1, ':p:h'))
        return
    endif
    return mkdir(fnamemodify(a:1, ':p:h'), 'p')
endfunction
command -bang -bar -nargs=? -complete=file E :call s:MKDir(<f-args>) | e<bang> <args>
```

This command is intended to be a replacement for built-in `:e`.

Conditions in which mkdir is not run (in order):

1. Command is run without arguments
2. Command is run with `` `generate filename` ``  or `` `=generate_filename()` `` backticks filename generators or with `+command`/`++opt` switches.
3. Command contains more then one argument or has unescaped special characters.
4. Argument is a directory.
5. Argument is an existing file.
6. Argument is a file in an existing directory.

In last three cases nothing should be done, second and third cases are not impossible to handle, just more complicated.

<s>The above is ready for adding a `cnoreabbrev`:</s>

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> e ((getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'e')?'E':'e')
```

`-complete=file` spoils things: it add not only completion, but also arguments processing (thus checking for `` ` `` expansion and special characters presence does not make sense) and forbids having multiple “filenames” (thus no ++opt).

`-bar` makes you unable to use `` `="String"` `` because `"` now starts a comment. Without `-bar` it is not a `:e` emulation because you can’t do `E file | another command`.

Another version:

```
function s:MKDir(...)
    if         !a:0 
           \|| isdirectory(a:1)
           \|| filereadable(a:1)
           \|| isdirectory(fnamemodify(a:1, ':p:h'))
        return
    endif
    return mkdir(fnamemodify(a:1, ':p:h'), 'p')
endfunction
command -bang -bar -nargs=? -complete=file E :call s:MKDir(<f-args>) | e<bang> <args>
```

Comment: Wish there was a proper plugin for this.

Answer (score 31):

```
:!mkdir -p spec/models
:w spec/models/blog_spec.rb
```

Comment: @davidtbernal Wrap it in a function.

Comment: Point is that the question was explicitly 'in one step', so this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 18):

If you encounter this often it may be worthwhile to add a command for it.

```
command -nargs=1 E execute('silent! !mkdir -p "$(dirname "<args>")"') <Bar> e <args>
```

If you add that line in your .vimrc file, you can simply use it like this:

```
:E spec/models/blog_spec.rb
```

Edit This will only work on Linux/Mac, not Windows.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, better than the accepted answer. This worked really well for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing is that this answer doesn't have tab-completion for paths. In the example above, if the `spec` model existed but the `models` didn't, you'd have to type out `spec` instead of `sp<Tab>`

Answer (score 2):

I generally find that the parent directories don't already exist *only after* trying to save the file.

[This code](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2011/11/saving-files-in-nonexistent-directories-with-vim/) will prompt you to create the directory with `:w`, or just do it with `:w!`:

```
augroup vimrc-auto-mkdir
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePre * call s:auto_mkdir(expand('<afile>:p:h'), v:cmdbang)
  function! s:auto_mkdir(dir, force)
    if !isdirectory(a:dir)
          \   && (a:force
          \       || input("'" . a:dir . "' does not exist. Create? [y/N]") =~? '^y\%[es]$')
      call mkdir(iconv(a:dir, &encoding, &termencoding), 'p')
    endif
  endfunction
augroup END
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! oftentimes, I don't want to think about whether the path exists before editing a file. I only worry about it when I'm ready to save the file.